# Find the general solution to the given equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution to the given equation 
$$3x{"} - 4x{'} +x = e^t +e^{-t}$$

I know how to solve a given task using the Variation of Parameters method, however I would also like to know how to do that without it.

We have:

$$y = y_{h} + y_{p}$$
So finding the general solution to the homogenous equation is quite easy.

$$x_h = c_1e^{x/3} + c_2e^x$$

Now I have a problem with finding the particular solution to the non homogenous equation.

My first guess was to use $x = Ae^t + Be^{-t}$ and then using it in $3x{''}-4x'+x = e^t+e^{-t}$, but it does not seem to work (I don't really know why)

So my question is, what should be my $x$?

Comment: Try $x(t) = (c_1+c_2 t)e^t+(c_3+c_4 t)e^{-t}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $e^t$ is already a homogeneous solution, that's why you can't use it as a particular guess. Try

$$ x_p(t) = Ate^t + Be^{-t} $$

Comment: Thank you. Good to know this fact.